# Partitioning of data in adx table

Tags: partitioning, azure-data-explorer, database-partitioning, adx

I was going through the microsoft docs of partition policy [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/partitioningpolicy). There it is written that `By default, extents are partitioned by time of creation (ingestion), and in most cases there's no need to set a data partitioning policy.`
Whereas in the later part of document, I found the line - `By default, a table's data partitioning policy is null, in which case data in the table won't be repartitioned after it's ingested.`

What does these 2 statements mean?

I found out that there is no partitioning policy present in newly created table.

In my use case I want partitioning of data based on the `ingestionTime`.

How should I create the partition policy if that is not present by default?

- partition by ingestion/creation time?
- partition by timestamp(dateTime) column?

I want uniform range partitioning as the hash partition does not make sense here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By default, extents are partitioned by time of creation (ingestion), and in most cases there's no need to set a data partitioning policy

this means that when a data partitioning policy isn't defined (is null), data still gets partitioned (into data shards) by time of arrival (i.e. ingestion time).  data does *not* get *re*-partitioned after it is ingested.

> By default, a table's data partitioning policy is null, in which case data in the table won't be repartitioned after it's ingested

this means the same as the above.

> In my use case I want partitioning of data based on the ingestion time.

you don't need to define a partitioning policy. that happens by default (as explained above).